# Facebook deprecating login support on Android WebViews?

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, android-webview, facebook-login

We are using “react-native-app-auth” plugin for OAuth using gmail, facebook and microsoft login but after Facebook deprecating login support on Android WebViews is we require any implementation changes in our application to support the facebook login.

As we are not using Facebook SDK for Android directly, we are depends on "react-native-app-auth" plugin implementation but we are not sure what "react-native-app-auth" plugin using internally for facebook login, its webview or custom-tab. So we are worried about if facebook disables webview support will our application will work fine or not.

Even Facebook not provide any sandbox environment for testing this case.

Any help or suggestion will be valuable for us.

Comment: We have less time than a month, we need a update on it. anybody have anything  about this issue please update.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference, that I am have not used the plugin “react-native-app-auth”, this bellow solution is for whom has developed from scratch the OAuth.

I have solved this by replacing **SafariView** and **WebView** by **Linking** react-native package to open the url, this will open your url on an external device browser instead of embedded one.

```
    `import { Linking } from 'react-native;`
```

```
    `Linking.openURL(url);`
```